# Why pundit can't find policies in controller tests?

Tags: ruby, testing, automated-tests, bdd, pundit

The controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ...
    authorize User
  end
  ...
```

The policy:

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def index
    @user.admin?
  end
end
```

The test:

```
class UsersControllerAuthorizationTest < ActionController::TestCase
  tests :users

  def user
    @user ||= create(:user)
  end

  test 'should not authorize ordinary users to access the page' do
    sign_in user
    get :index
    assert_response :error
  end
end
```

The app fails with `Pundit::NotAuthorizedError (not allowed to index? this User)` as expected. But the test says:

```
Pundit::NotDefinedError: unable to find policy UserPolicy for User
```

Am I doing it wrong? Can I make it find the policy?

**UPD** It must have to do with `rails`' autoloading. Calling [`constantize`](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/blob/v0.3.0/lib/pundit/policy_finder.rb#L17) on `'UserPolicy'` makes it autoload `app/policies/user_policy.rb` in case of the app, and doesn't, in case of the tests.

**UPD** The problem supposedly laid in `spring`. After stopping it, the tests now output:

```
Pundit::NotAuthorizedError: not allowed to index? this User
```

Answer (score 7):

To fix this issue, I ran:

```
bin/spring stop
bin/spring binstub --remove --all
bundle update spring
bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of time with Rails 5.0.2 running API-only.

Comment: Happy to hear that!

Comment: Also worked for me. Thanks. Would not have figured this out, why does this work?

Comment: I'm unsure! But given the spring related errors I tried that out when having the same issues and it cleared out something that needed a restart.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you have:

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def index
    @user.admin?
  end
end
```

I think that you're missing a question mark:

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def index?                 # <-- Added ? to method name <---
    @user.admin?
  end
end
```